# Webapi Cors No Access Allowed Origin

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Will try to make this as short as possible.  Using the Northwind sample db.  Created a Webapi project db first.  Created a northwind edmx model and let it create all the model classes.  Then created web client layer to call db to get a list of all the products.  Worked perfect.

So after reading that best practices was not to actually call the model itself for various reason create and use View Models.  So I created repository created few VMs, from the client layer called the controller stepped through to repository query ran fine collected expected results returned to control then at that point hit 500 error no access control allowed origin??  In the WebApiConfig cors is enabled.  At the controller level cors is enabled for the client request.

So in this case why using the models created does this work but when switching to view models this does not work.

```
                var result = entites.Products.ToList(); <-- this works same contrller

            //var result = from p in entites.Products <-- same controller this doenst work
            //             join o in entites.Order_Details on p.ProductID equals o.ProductID
            //             select new ProductVm
            //             {
            //                 ProductName = p.ProductName,
            //                 QuantityPerUnit = p.QuantityPerUnit,
            //                 UnitPrice = p.UnitPrice.Value,
            //                 UnitsInStock = p.UnitsInStock.Value,
            //                 UnitsOnOrder = p.UnitsOnOrder.Value,
            //                 ReorderLevel = p.ReorderLevel.Value,
            //                 OrderDetails = p.Order_Details.Select(x =>
            //                 new OrderDetailVm
            //                 {
            //                     ProductId = o.ProductID
            //                 })
            //             };
            //returning VM causes 500 error no access control origin using same controller
            return result;
```

WebApiConfig

```
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.EnableCors();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{search}",
            defaults: new { search = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Start of controller:

```
    [EnableCors("http://localhost:54575", "*,", "*,")]
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
```

Comment: can you show how you actually enabled cors?

Comment: If you’re getting a 500 error it means something is broken/failing on the server side that must be fixed, and any CORS-related message you’re seeing is just incidental and unrelated. It’s probably just that like many (most) servers, it doesn’t send the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header for 500 errors

Comment: exactly what the problem was when I set api as start up and ran it.  Received serialized error then realized result needed to be result.ToList();

Answer (score 0):

```
            var result = from p in entites.Products
                         join o in entites.Order_Details on p.ProductID equals o.ProductID
                         select new ProductVm
                         {
                             ProductName = p.ProductName,
                             QuantityPerUnit = p.QuantityPerUnit,
                             UnitPrice = p.UnitPrice.Value,
                             UnitsInStock = p.UnitsInStock.Value,
                             UnitsOnOrder = p.UnitsOnOrder.Value,
                             ReorderLevel = p.ReorderLevel.Value,
                             OrderDetails = p.Order_Details.Select(x =>
                             new OrderDetailVm
                             {
                                 ProductId = o.ProductID
                             })
                         };

            return result.ToList();
```